# How to I pass my postgres connection pool to Dask workers with psycopg2 or asyncpg?

Tags: python-asyncio, psycopg2, dask, dask-distributed, asyncpg

I want my Dask workers to grab a Postgres connection from a `ThreadedConnectionPool`, but when passing the pool like so

```
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

def worker_pg(n, pool) -> None:
    print(n)

work = db.from_sequence(range(4))
tcp = ThreadedConnectionPool(1, 800, "db_string")

work.map(worker_pg, pool=tcp).compute()
```

I get serialization errors such as:

```
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type ThreadedConnectionPool.', '<psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool object at 0x7f99dc57b128>')
```

Also, while I have been trying this with `psycopg2` I'd also really like this to work with `asyncpg` (performance reasons). However, this has the added wrinkle of using `await` and `async` from `asyncio`

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg

async def get_pool():
    p = await asyncpg.create_pool("db_string")
    return p

pool = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_pool())

work.map(worker_pg, pool=pool).compute()
```

although I do seem to end up with the same type of errors like

```
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type Pool.', '<asyncpg.pool.Pool object at 0x7fdee9127818>')
```

Any suggestions (or alternatives?) are much appreciated!

Comment: Why not connect inside the worker instead? Each worker handles its own connection without the need to worry about global/shared objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you might consider having each of your tasks open up a connection to Postgres, perform a query, and then close that connection.

Unfortunately Dask can not move an active database connection between machines.  These objects are closely tied to the process in which they are started.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a simple wrapper on top of your job to make it use it's own database connection. Here's a quick example - probably this can be optimized further according to your needs.

```
def my_task(conn, more_args):
    """Use psycopg2 conn to run a task"""
    
    # Something complicated here
    pass

def run_my_task(more_args):
    """Wraps my_task and gives it its own conn"""
    with psycopg2.connect(...) as conn:
        my_task(conn, more_args)

run_my_task = dask.delayed(run_my_task)
jobs = []
for i in range(10):
    jobs.append(run_my_task(i))
dask.compute(*jobs)
```